# Understanding SQL Server 2008 Security, Logins, Roles etc

Tags: sql-server

I having trouble understanding some core concepts in SQL Server 2008. Until recently I haven't had to care much about security, users, schemas etc.

1. What is the difference between a Login and a User?
2. How do these relate to roles
3. What is a schema? (Until I started reading about security I thought a schema was just a database design?!)
4. I'd like to be able to create a script to create my Users, Logins, especially as IIS attempts to connect to SQL Server as it's app pool. Can anyone point me in the direction of some examples of scripting this kind of thing?

Thanks in advance!

P.S:
I've been trying to read some MSDN articles about this stuff and getting a bit lost for example this seemed out of my depth:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190387.aspx

Answer (score 7):

1. A **login** is the principal that is used to connect to the server.  A **user** is the principal that is used to connect to a database.  The security context on the instance itself is dictated by the **login**, it's roles and the permissions granted/denied.  The security context on the database is dictated by the **user**, it's roles and the permissions granted/denied.
2. Like all other role based systems, the **roles** are logical groupings of permissions.  Roles can be applied to users and logins.  There are **fixed server roles** and **fixed database roles** for frequently used sets of permissions.
3. A **schema** is a database object that is used for two things:  logical separation of database objects (tables, stored procs, functions, views), and security separation.  A **schema** contains these objects.  And users can be granted/denied rights on schemas, implicitly granting/denying rights on the objects contained within.

4 doesn't really seem like a question.  Can you reword??

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation. I re worded the 4th point into a question.