# Should I let EF CF create my tables with the user "dbo"?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbo

I am just starting out with SQL Server and I let Entity Framework code first create my data tables. Here's the SQL for one of the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserProfile] (
    [UserId]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC)
);
```

I notice "dbo" but I am not sure what this means. Is this similar to the data being stored in the master database? Now I would like to manually drop / create tables instead of letting EF do this.

Can someone tell me if there is a better way for me to create the tables. Should I for instance create them with something other than dbo? Also can I create multiple databases within my SQL Server and then place my tables there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dbo` stands for 'database owner'. It is simply the default schema in SQL Server. EF Code first uses the `dbo` schema by default. If you want to overide, see:

[How can I stop Entity Framework 5 migrations adding dbo. into key names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053627/how-can-i-stop-entity-framework-5-migrations-adding-dbo-into-key-names)

[Schemas are used to group objects. For instance, a `Report` schema might contain read-only views used for reporting.]

Comment: Thanks - So would a system normally store it's user login information under dbo or would it create a different owner?

Comment: Logins, though related, are different things. You grant access rights to the dbo schema to a user or role, which is then associated with a login

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973134/understanding-sql-server-2008-security-logins-roles-etc